# Why does this fail in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, cross-browser

This is a common piece of JavaScript used to show a customer splash screen in Silverlight:

```
function onSourceDownloadProgressChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
            var myHost = document.getElementById("Xaml1");
            var rectBar = myHost.content.findName("rectBar");
            var rectBorder = myHost.content.findName("rectBorder");
            if (eventArgs.progress)
                rectBar.Width = eventArgs.progress * rectBorder.Width;
            else
                rectBar.Width = eventArgs.get_progress() * rectBorder.Width;
        }
```

For some reason, Firefox and Chrome get errors on this line:

```
var rectBar = myHost.content.findName("rectBar");
```

They complain that **"myHost is null"**.

This works fine in Internet Explorer, but in Firefox and Chrome the progress bar is never updated because of this error.

The key portion it is traversing looks like this:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object id="xaml1" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/MyApp.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <param name="splashscreensource" value="ClientBin/SplashScreen.xaml" />    
          <param name="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" value="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's `xaml1`, not `Xaml1`, and Internet Explorer is too lazy to care about your typo.

Comment: Good catch.  I am surprised I did not pick that up.

Comment: @NissanFan: For future reference, an error like this from such a simple assignment almost always points to a typo like this. :)

Answer (score 3):

because the other browsers are case-sensitive. "Xaml1" != "xaml1"